# Where are the common typeclasses instances in scalaz?

Tags: scalaz

I'm trying to understand how scalaz is organized, and I would like to know where the common monad (or other typeclasses) instances like Monad[Int], Monad[List] ... are defined.

Take for example the Monad[List]. I saw that the scalaz.std module contains the ListInstances trait which contains implicit values for some typeclass instances of lists, like Monoid[List]. This implicit value defines the append function for the list instance of monoid.

Is there a place where to find an implicit value for Monad[List], which defines point and bind for lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the `Monad` instance and other instances like `Monoid` for `List`: [ListInstances](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/List.scala). As you can see there's no `Monad[List]` instance but a `MonadPlus[List]` instance. A `MonadPlus` is a `Monad` plus an `ApplicativePlus` (no pun intended).

In general there's a `trait`, `AllInstances`, that mixes in *all instances* and you can find it [here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/AllInstances.scala).